# How to force the user to enter an specific number in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

By using `TextEditingController` in Flutter, I'm trying to force the user to enter a number that starts with zero and then the number 4 or 8, then enter whatever he wants. Like this:

```
04****** or 08******
```

What should I do?

My code:

```
 TextFormField(
                       maxLength: 10,
                          controller: _inputdat,
                          inputFormatters: [ FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,],
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number),
               ElevatedButton(
                      ......
                        onPressed: () async {
                          if (_inputdat.text.length < 10
                             || !RegExp(r'^[0][8/4/2]{1}[0-9]{8}$').hasMatch(value))
                          {
                            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                                backgroundColor: Color(0xff446d74),
                                content: Text(
                                  "Error",
                                )));
```

What's wrong with my code? I got the error: Undefined name 'value'.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex in the TextFormFiled validator `r'^0[48][0-9]{7}$'`

---

If you want to specify a specific number in total you can specify it in this part `[0-9]{7}` instead of seven you can choose different number.

This regex has in total of 9 numbers:

start with Zero `0`

Second choose one 4 or 8 `[48]`

Third choose any 7 number `[0-9]{7}`

---

The validator should look something like this:

```
  validator: (value) {
                      if (value!.isEmpty || !RegExp(r'^0[48][0-9]{7}$').hasMatch(value)) {
                        return "error message";
                      } else {
                        return null;
                      }
                    },
```

---

initialize a form key like below:

```
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

Full code:

```
Form(
      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
      key: formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          TextFormField(
              validator: (value) {
                if (value!.isEmpty || !RegExp(r'^0[48][0-9]{7}$').hasMatch(value)) {
                  return "error message";
                } else {
                  return null;
                }
              },
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                errorMaxLines: 2, // specify how many error lines you want
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'number',
              ),
              maxLength: 10,
              controller: _inputdat,
              inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                // do something like a function or toast message etc...
              }
            },
            child: const Text('Confirm'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: i have edited my post , i add my code .

Comment: A note on the regex, the expression `[4/8]` matches the characters `4`, `8` *and* `/` which is probably not intended. You can remove the slash to make it match only `4` and `8`.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 can u elaborate please , because the `/` mean `OR` , so it will be 4 OR 8, and it is working fine with me!.

Comment: @7eg No, the slash in character groups does not mean `or`. Have a look at the breakdown on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SZD4iT/1). It does cover the usecase asked but too much: `0/1234567` also matches the regex in your answer which is not supposed to be a valid input.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 Thank you so much for the clarification, I learned something today, Could you please write the correct one so that I can edit my answer Or edit my answer.Thanks

Comment: @geisterfurz007 This is the right way `[48]{1}`  right?

Comment: Yes, that won't allow slashes anymore. Actually, looking at it again, it could be improved even further: `^0[48][0-9]{7}$`. I removed the brackets around the 0 (a character group with a single character is equal to the character itself) and I removed the `{1}` after `[48]` because a character group implicitly means exactly one of the contained characters unless a quantifier (like `?` or `*`) are specified.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://pub.dev/packages/mask_text_input_formatter and do something like this:

```
var maskFormatter = new MaskTextInputFormatter(
  mask: '0*########', 
  filter: { "*": RegExp(r'[48]'), "#": RegExp(r'[0-9]') },
  type: MaskAutoCompletionType.lazy
);
```

and then pass maskFormatter to your text filed

```
TextField(inputFormatters: [maskFormatter])
```

Comment: i have edited my post , i add my code .